# Need to use jQuery.find to find element with specific style

Tags: jquery, find

Right... I need to find all < ul style="display: block;"> elements, so that I can set it do display:none.

I think I'm on the right path here... but not quite there:

```
jQuery('#adminMenu li').find("ul").css('display');
```

For advance users: how can I find and change the style with one line?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That's tricky as stated but is solvable other ways. The easiest is:

```
$("#adminMenu li ul:visible").hide();
```

assuming items are either hidden or not. Of course, considering you want to hide them all why not just:

```
$("#adminMenu li ul").hide();
```

Try and avoid changing CSS style directly. It's problematic. It's hard to reverse and as you're discovering hard to search for. Use a class instead:

```
#adminMenu li ul { display: none; }
ul.block { display: block; }
```

with:

```
$("#adminMenu li ul").removeClass("block");
```

or

```
$("#adminMenu li ul.block").removeClass("block");
```

Answer (score 39):

You may be able to use the attribute selectors, and the 'contains' option

```
$('#adminMenu li ul[style*="display:block"]').hide()
```

This essentially says 'any ul who's style attribute contains the text display:block'

Comment: For me (in jQuery-1.9.0) this gives `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ul[style*=display:block]`

Comment: Edited to include the missing quotes

Comment: This is a good idea to use that wildcard selector. I wonder if it's faster than the other suggestions. OP: you may want to consider a broader target though. For example, if there was, for whatever reason, a perfectly valid space between `display: block` this would not work. But this would `[style*="block"]` assuming it's not too broad for your purpose.

Comment: for me its working when I added space between `display:` and `block` - for example `$('#adminMenu li ul[style*="display: block"]').hide()`
jquery - 3.3.1

Answer (score 9):

You can use filter. (http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

So you can do as below.

```
$('ul').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('display') == 'block';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#adminMenu li').find("ul:visible").css('display', 'none');
```

or

```
$('#adminMenu li').find("ul:visible").hide();
```

or

```
$('#adminMenu li ul:visible').hide();
```

to name a few ways

Answer (score 0):

You coud use the fadeOut() or slideUp() methods for a visual effect:

```
jQuery('#adminMenu li').find("ul").fadeOut('fast');

jQuery('#adminMenu li').find("ul").slideUp('fast');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#adminMenu li ul').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think I have the wrong answer, it is more this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562634/need-to-use-jquery-find-to-find-element-with-specific-style/1562680#1562680

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to do it in one line, but here's how you can do it in a couple more:

```
jQuery('#adminMenu li').find("ul").each(function (){
  if($(this).css("display") == "block"){
    // do something
  }
});
```

If what you want is to handle all visible elements (instead of only the `display: block` ones), you could try the `:visible` selector instead.