# Go to table row where color equals

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table where I need to automatically scroll to the highlighted row, so this is the code I thought of:

```
            var container = $('#table_id'),
        scrollTo = $("table tr background-color:contains('#FFCC66')");
        container.scrollTop(
            scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
        );
```

Where "#FFCC66" is the background-color of the row I am highlighting

This returns the error:

```
Error: Unable to get property 'top' of undefined or null reference
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: show us the html to which this relates

Comment: Try console logging each variable to see if they even exist. `console.log(scrollTo, container)`

Comment: Is `"table tr background-color:contains('#FFCC66')"` even a valid way of searching? According to jquery, contains is for containing text, not attributes. Wouldn't you need to see whether the style attribute contains it? If its even set? I'de assume like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562634/need-to-use-jquery-find-to-find-element-with-specific-style

Comment: While others may give good answers on how to achieve what you're asking for, I would strongly recommend marking the row in some other way to indicate that it's highlighted -- maybe with a class name or a data attribute. If you check directly against the colour, your code runs the risk of being difficult to maintain in the future, say if you decide to change the colour scheme of your site.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a class to the highlighted element and then do:

```
var container = $('#table_id'),
    scrollTo = $("table tr.highlighted");

container.length && container.scrollTop(
        scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
);
```

Or the way you're doing it, this should work:

```
var container = $('#table_id'),
    scrollTo = $("table tr").filter(function() {
        return $(this).css('background-color').toLowerCase() == '#ffcc66';
    });

container.length && container.scrollTop(
        scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var 
  container = $('#table_id'),
  scrollTo = undefined;
$("table tr").each(function() {
  if ($(this).css('background-color').indexOf('#FFCC66') !== -1) {
    scrollTo = $(this);
  }
});
if (scrollTo) {
//--> continue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to this snippet, it automatically scroll to the selected row after one second:

```js
window.setTimeout(scrollToSelected, 1000);
function scrollToSelected () {
    var container = $('#table_id'),
        scrollTo = $("table tr.selected");
    window.scrollTo(0, scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top);
}
```

```css
td {
    height: 50px;
}

tr.selected {
    background-color: #AAAAAA;
}

tr {
    background-color: #000000;
}

tr, table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_id">
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr class="selected"><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
```