# how can i delete parent div with style display none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my div with style display none have a anchor tag on click of that I want to delete the complete div

my div will be append on click

code is

```
<div class="row" id="mainContainer">
  <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4">
    <label for="Education">Education</label>
  </div>
  <div class=class="col-md-8 col-xs-8  verticalLine" id="nestedFeilds" style=" margin-left: 10px ;float:left; display: none">
    <a href="" style="color: red;margin-left: auto; ">Delete Education</a>
    <input type="text" placeholder="School Name" class="form-control" id="School_Name" required="" name="School_Name[]"> |
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Feild of Study" class="form-control" id="feild_Name" required="" name="feild_Name[]">
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Degree" class="form-control" id="Degree_Name" required="" name="Degree_Name[]">
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="2ndmainContainer">
  <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8  verticalLine" id="showhere" style=" margin-left: 10px ;float:left;"></div>
  <div style="margin-left: 120px; float:left;"><a id="addNew"> Add Education</a></div>
</div>
</form>
```

I am firing function on click but nothing is happening

my function is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.close-div').on('click', function(){
      alert("hh");
    });     
});
```

Comment: I am unable to see any element with class `close-div` in your code. your delete link have no class. so code won't work . Also since div is `display:none;` and link is inside it (as i saw in your code) .So your link is physically not visible (you are not able to see it on browser) then how you can click on it?

Comment: you can do <script> document.getElementById('divyouwanttotarget').onclick = alert("hi");</script>  But there isn't any close-div element on your page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to use jQuery.find to find element with specific style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562634/need-to-use-jquery-find-to-find-element-with-specific-style)

Comment: since div is `display:none;` and link is inside it (as i saw in your code) .So your link is physically not visible (you are not able to see it on browser) then how you can click on it?

Comment: @AlivetoDie yes you are right then how can I delete this

Comment: LOL  3 answers there for deleting a div which is not shown on browser

Comment: @AlivetoDie  I am appending  my display none div to  display block div on every click  and want that divs to be deleted

Comment: @RamshaQasim  can you show me a sample html of displayed div along with it's partner hide div?Also is the link is avialable in visible div? that is million dollor question

Comment: yes it is available  on visible div

Comment: https://screenshots.firefox.com/42LVyC5793eT0DAQ/localhost

Comment: by clicking add education the entire html of hidden div append like this

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are getting at, and thats only from piecing it together from your name 2ndmainContainer, so hopefully there is a maincontainer.
What you need to do is target the main container and just blank out the html inside of it or you can replace the following html,

```
<script>function makeDisappear(){document.getElementByiD('maindiv').outerHTML =''; }</script>
```

will target the div tag itself and erase any tags, if you use .innerHTML you can place something inside the tags.
You wrap this in an anchor link thats tied to a function with your target div element that remains inside. `<a click="makeDisappear()"> div in here </a>` But again I am trying to piece this together from your question. More details would help.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a class to select the anchor tag but you haven't set the class attribute to the `a` html element. Set the attribute in your html code first...

```
<a href="" class="close-div" style="color: red;margin-left: auto; ">Delete Education</a>
```

... and then the click event should work...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.close-div').on('click',function() {
        alert("hh");
    });     
});
```

Then, if you want to hide the container div when you click that anchor...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.close-div').on('click',function() {
        $(this).closest('div#nestedFeilds').hide();
    });     
});
```

... or if you want to remove it from the DOM...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.close-div').on('click',function() {
        $(this).closest('div#nestedFeilds').remove();
    });     
});
```

NOTE: There's a typo in your html code where you duplicate the class attribute...

```
<div class=class="col-md-8 col-xs-8 verticalLine" id=...
```

... just change it for...

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8 verticalLine" id=...
```

Comment: sir I already did that but not working actually my div is display none and I cant to block to it

Comment: sorry for late reply

Answer (score 0):

try this

insert class **close-div** from anchor tag 
and that anchor tag you will place after this  **id="nestedFeilds"** div. Or where you want check before execute that will make visible.

Then you will traverse parent tag like

```
   $(".close-div").parents("DIV.your parent class").find(".your wanted class").attr("attrute-name");
```

Answer (score 0):

First change your div's display to block, then:

```
    $("#nestedFeilds").on("click","a",function(){
        $("#nestedFeilds").remove();
    });
```

Comment: sir I cant block the div I need it to be display none